# FastPass Accessibility Pattern Updates

Tags: accessibility-insights

FastPass is reporting that a  requires an ARIA child role of *textbox*; however, based on this [GitHub combobox pattern accessibility](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/20082#issuecomment-686622547) thread, the issue is that the rules is adhering to the ARIA 1.1 spec and not the latest ARIA 1.2 spec which does **not** require it.

I believe FastPass utilizes axe-core as its accessibility rule engine and I based on request [2505](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/2505), it does not appear they have completed the work to adhere to this combobox spec in this specific situation.

Is the best guidance to wait for axe-core to complete the work or can the rule be disabled for now?

Comment: A comment (https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/2505#issuecomment-876767719) on the 2505 post (https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/issues/2505) indicates the update will be part of an upcoming 4.3 release (week of 7/11/2021-7/17/2021)

Answer (score 0):

The automated checks in Accessibility Insights are powered by axe-core and we try to maintain our rule set close to the axe-core rules. In general, ARIA 1.2 is not an official recommendation yet but in particular for this pattern, from the  linked GitHub issue in the  Axe-core repo, the last comment is that this will be taken up in the 4.3 release. This rule impacts more than just comboboxes (the rule checks several ARIA roles that are parent roles and require children attributes) and turning it off would mean not catching issues in many widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ahmed.  With 4.1.4 being the latest release, what is the SWAG on when 4.3 will be released?  In the interim, I guess we would just disregard the flagged alert as won't fix.

Comment: I don't think we have an estimation when 4.3 will be released, that's up to axe-core, and you're right for now it will be as it is till 4.3 is released

Comment: I see axe-core https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core/releases/tag/v4.3.0 was released today.  Any idea when FastPass will pick it up?  Latest v2.27 was released on 6/2/2021.

Comment: Thanks for the question. We are aware of the latest release and we will be working on picking that version in the upcoming weeks